# I'm unable to use parsed variable from http request widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm using Twilio Studio. Within I'm using the Make HTTP Request widget to hit an api endpoint.

After that I'm using a Say/Play widget to say one of the variables from Make HTTP Request. `{{widgets.http_1.body}}` works fine with api response:

```
{ "message": "Hello World", "completed": true }
```

However, if I want to return {{widgets.http_1.parsed.message}} the say text portion for this will be empty.

What might be wrong here? I can see the endpoint I hit with the Make HTTP Request step returns a 200 & the json is valid.

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roKSQ.png) - [Make HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvnaC.png) - [Say Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFDPy.png)

Comment: Nginx was also sending a default header of application/octet-stream. Once this was removed and application/json was substituted everything worked great.

Comment: You can find more details about how you can parse the HTTP json response here https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request#how-to-access-variables-from-your-http-response

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your [screenshot of the Say widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFDPy.png) shows that you are using `{{ widgets.http_1.body.parsed.message }}`. When using the parsed data, you don't need the `body` in there, so it should just be:

```
{{ widgets.http_1.parsed.message }}
```